# In symfony is there a way to made a entity without database?

Tags: php, api, symfony

In symfony 2.8 is there a way to use in a API application entity without storing in database to use form and validation to validate the post data without making all the validation in the controller ( not blank, numeric data, length x ... )?
Maybe by using an abstract entity?

Comment: Entities are just objects.  No need for any database mapping stuff at all if you don't need it.  Validation is completely independent of the database.  Maybe take a peak at the validation and form component docs.

Comment: yes I will try without annotation on database like t-n-y have sugessted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply don't put the annotation (is you use annotations) that tell to store the data in the database, exemple :

usually you have :

```
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $userId;
```

simply write it like that :

```
/**
 * @var int
 */
protected $userId;
```

Comment: great , don't forget to give feedback and to put it as solved if it is what you want